# Android 10 on car doesn't have a sleep mode option

Tags: android-10, standby, sleep, automotive-head-unit

I got a head unit in my car that runs android 10. I'm kind of disappoint with this unit, and the most annoying thing is the loading time at boot, since I need to go reverse and need to wait for the rear camera.

I saw on youtube that there is an option to make the device not going to sleep for hours/days (under Settings > Car settings)... but I can't find "Car settings" on my device. I was also looking for it under Settings > Display, but no luck again.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Youtube videos are usually a bad information source especially as each manufacturer may modify Android e.g. by adding new featured and options. Therefore unless the car was the same model from the same manufacturer the video is no applicable to your car. If the boot time is too long you should complain at the car manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

I am new so I may be totally wrong here but...

You could root the device and change the sleep file/delete it.

Also, for me personally, I would take maybe 20 minutes to study all the device's content especially the settings.

Cheers!